# Apexchart graph updateseries function not working?

Tags: javascript, json, django, ajax, apexcharts

Working on Apexcharts but my Updateseries in AJAX Call not working. Whenever I insert dates in datepicker in front. Data is coming from backend as I can see in my console but Update Series/Graph is not updating in front end.

Working in Django Framework.

Please share as many examples of UpdateSeries in Apex Charts as possible